# Counting the occurrence of a substring from a delimited field

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have some data that looks like:

```
Sequence, length
abc, 1
bat, 1
abc > abc, 2
abc > bat, 2
ced > ced > ced > fan, 4
```

I'm trying to see the frequency of various strings as a new column to this data. For example:

```
Sequence, length, count_of_ced
abc, 1, 0
bat, 1, 0
abc > abc, 2, 0
abc > bat, 2, 0
ced > ced > ced > fan, 4, 3
```

I was trying to go about this by taking the length value and subtracting the Sequence field's length with the "ced" string replaced to "" like so:

```
length - array_length(split(replace(Sequence, "ced", ""), " > " )) as count_of_ced
```

however all the results from this line yield 0.

Is this the right approach? I've tested this both with the string split on " > " and ">" but I still get 0 for both. I've dug through the Google Bigquery documentation some and haven't found a pre-built substring_count() function or anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the tried and true string length method:

```
select (length(replace(sequence, 'ced', 'ced+')) - length(sequence)) as num_ced
```

Or, you can use arrays:

```
select array_length(regexp_extract_all(sequence, 'ced'))
```

Comment: The second one was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Below version is using 'ced' as a separator for split

```
SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(Sequence, 'ced')) - 1
```

You can test it using dummy data from your question as in below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'abc' Sequence, 1 length UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bat', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc > abc', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc > bat', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ced > ced > ced > fan', 4 
)
SELECT Sequence, length, 
  ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(Sequence, 'ced')) - 1 AS count_of_ced
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result as

```
Row Sequence                length  count_of_ced     
1   abc                     1       0    
2   bat                     1       0    
3   abc > abc               2       0    
4   abc > bat               2       0    
5   ced > ced > ced > fan   4       3
```